# Implement Icon In React Native

Tags: react-native

I have seen in several articles about applying icons to this react native, but on my way I found an error. it's clearer like this

Step that i did :

1. `npm intall react-native-vector-icons --save`

then in **Example.js**

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';

export defaul class App extends React.Component {
   render(){ 
       return(       
          <Icon name='person-outline' type="MaterialIcons" />
       )
   }
}
```

after I got here I tried it, but the icon didn't work.
then I read a few articles, and needed to execute the following command. and i do

```
react-native link react-native-vector-icons
```

and I tried again. and this works. the icon appears.
but in the command I get an error.
more or less error like this

** *error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually:
  - react-native-vector-icons (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-vector-icons")* **

what should i do??

Comment: if you are using rn 0.60> then react-native unlink react-native-vector-icons first and then try with some other icons. if its still not working tell

Comment: I use npm 0.60 <higher. and I have done this command `react-native unlink react-native-vector-icons`. but icon not work again. so how can it work @GauravRoy

Answer (score 1):

In your scenario once you are using React Native Version 0.60 or above you don't need to link packages manually. [Autolinking](https://reactnative.dev/blog/2019/07/03/version-60) will do that for you

If you need to remove this warning try this command

```
react-native unlink react-native-vector-icons
```

If you are still using React Native version 0.59 or less then you need to link those packages.

**EXTRA**

> But you can also disable autolinking for unsupported library

During the transition period some packages may not support autolinking on certain platforms. To disable autolinking for a package, update your react-native.config.js's dependencies entry to look like this:

// react-native.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  dependencies: {
    'some-unsupported-package': {
      platforms: {
        android: null, // disable Android platform, other platforms will still autolink if provided
      },
    },
  },
};
```